# URL argument passing from ajax to symfony2 controller via rounting.yml

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to pass argument in URL from jquery to symfony2 controller but the path seemed to be not found in the routing.yml file. please help me with that.

```
//jquery code
$.each(searchResult, function(key, value){
         $("#course_list").append('<h4><a href="{{ path("FrontEndBundle_course", { "id" : '+value.id+' })            
}}">'+value.name+'</a></h4><p>'+value.description+'</p>')
     });
```

routing.yml

```
course:
  pattern: /course
  defaults: { _controller: FrontEndBundle:Course:index }
  requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

controller

```
public function indexAction($id)
    {
        return $this->render('FrontEndBundle:Course:course.html.twig',array("id"=>$id));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change js:

```
//jquery code
$.each(searchResult, function(key, value){
         $("#course_list").append('<h4><a href="{{ path("course", { "id" : '+value.id+' })            
}}">'+value.name+'</a></h4><p>'+value.description+'</p>')
     });
```

You forget `id` in `routing.yml`

```
course:
  pattern: /course/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: FrontEndBundle:Course:index }
  requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

Comment: @denys281........ its still not working. Showing...No route found for "GET /course"

Comment: @user3274692 when you have error? When render js? or when you go on the rendered link? Does your link from js render correctly? Update answer.

Comment: error occurs while URL look up in routing.yml. it says not found

Comment: you seem to be working with production environment. Make sure you clear cache by removing app/cache/prod folder or running command "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod"

Comment: also FrontEndBundle_course isnt a name of your route. It seem to be named as "course" ?